# UISearchDisplayController and custom cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have implemented a UISearchDisplayController in the UITableViewController. The search is working, but the UISearhDisplayController creates a new tableView with a standard cell, and my tableView is using a custom cell. Another problem is that I use a segue:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
```

and the cells in searchResultsTableView are not triggering the segue..

How to display the search results with custom cell and segue working?

This is the codes:

```
...

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView){ 
return [nameFilteredObj count];
} else {
return [sortedObj count];
}}

- (CustomCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"customCell";

CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
{
cell.textLabel.text = [[sortedObj objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Name"];
 } else {
cell.nameLabel.text = [[sortedObj objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Name"];
cell.countryLabel.text = [[sortedObj objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Country"];
cell.bottleImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[[sortedObj objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Image"]];
} 
return cell; 
}

//The codes for filtering the results and update of searchResultsTableView (not necessary for this question I think):

- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
[nameFilteredObj removeAllObjects];

for(NSDictionary *obj in sortedObj)
{
NSString *objName = [obj objectForKey:@"Name"];
NSRange range = [objName rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
    [nameFilteredObj addObject:obj];
}}}

- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
[self filterContentForSearchText:searchString scope:
 [[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];
return YES;}

- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchScope:(NSInteger)searchOption
{
[self filterContentForSearchText:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar text] scope:
 [[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:searchOption]];
return NO;}
...
```

I'm using Storyboard as interface.

Comment: Did you set `self.searchDislpayController.searchResultsDataSource` to `self`? And the `searchResultsDelegate`?

Comment: `self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsDataSource = self`. Do this where you create the search controller.

Comment: Add it after the line of code that creates the search display controller. Or maybe if this is done in Interface Builder you need to connect your view controller to the search display controller's data source and delegate properties. I don't use IB so I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: Ok, I use IB, I think I know how, thank you for the help.. Though the delegates were fine..

Answer (score -8, accepted):

Actually very easy to do, but I found many complicated half-working solutions on the way. Use this easy piece and SearchResultsTableView is GONE:

```
- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
...
self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.hidden=YES;
return YES;
}
```

Comment: How is this the solution? All you are doing is hiding the table view that should show the filtered results and showing the unfiltered tableview instead.