# Custom Cell not working in UITableView for Search Results

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

At the outset I would like to tell that I have researched and tried to follow stackoverflow links such as [UISearchDisplayController and custom cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13148389/uisearchdisplaycontroller-and-custom-cell?rq=1) but still the problem persists

I have Search Bar and Search Display controller integrated into my UITableView. The search functionality works fine but the search results cell have the default white cell design and not my custom cell design which is used for the UITableView. Below is my code to make the Search Result's Cell design adapt my custom design.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView registerClass:[ItemCellTableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if(!self.document){
        [self initDocument];
    }
    self.filteredItemCatalogArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.itemCatalogTableView.dataSource = self;
    self.itemCatalogTableView.delegate = self;
    [self.itemCatalogTableView reloadData];
    self.itemCatalogTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.itemCatalogTableView.opaque = NO;
    self.itemCatalogTableView.bounces = YES;
    self.itemCatalogTableView.backgroundView = nil;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    if(tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        //cell fields customization
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell.opaque = NO;
        return cell;
    }
    else
    {
        ItemCellTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        //cell fields customization
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell.opaque = NO;
        return cell;
    }
}
```

What am I missing here ?

EDITED :

In the if block for search results I changed tableview to self.tableview and it gets the correct custom cell. But it takes the incorrect height which is smaller and so overlaps the rows for search results

Comment: In the if block for search results I changed tableview to self.tableview and it get the correct custom cell. But it takes the incorrect height which is smaller and so overlaps the rows for search results

Comment: to rectify the height issue I added the following line in viewdidload
        self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.rowHeight = self.tableView.rowHeight ;

Answer (score 5):

In the if block for search results I changed tableview to self.tableview and it get the correct custom cell. But it takes the incorrect height which is smaller and so overlaps the rows for search results

to rectify the height issue I added the following line in viewdidload

> self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.rowHeight =
>   self.tableView.rowHeight ;

Comment: This only fixes single row.

Comment: This won't work if the search matches all entries. All the cells in the tableView will be dequeued and the height collapses. Set the height value to the actual value in pixels.

Comment: This is perfect answer!! working charming for me!! thanks for @Aditya parikh

Answer (score 1):

1) If your cell are using a xib file you should add to `viewDidLoad` (or other method that will be called before tableView delegate)

```
[yourTableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithtName:@"your_nibName" bunde:yourBunde] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"yourIdentifier"]
```

also you should use registred identifier for custom cell :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    static NSString *CustomCellIdentifier  = @"yourIdentifier";
    if(tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        // UITableViewCell customization
      return cell;
    }
    else
    {
        ItemCellTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CustomCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
          if (!cell)
                cell = [[ItemCellTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:yourPreferedStyle reuseIdentifier:CustomCellIdentifier] // or other custom initialization

        //put cell fields customization here
        return cell;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your custom cell is designed using a NIB try this

```
[self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"YourCellNibName" bundle:Nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
```

Comment: My custom cell was designed using Interface Builder in XCode 5

Comment: Yes its the same , the XIB file is also called a NIB.

Comment: OH Okay , in your cellForRowAtIndexPath and in the  `if(tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)` your are saying `UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];` should it not be  `ItemCellTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];`

Comment: Yes for customizing the custom label I need ItemCellTableViewCell but if don't add any lines for "cell fields customization", even then it should display the default custom cell defined in interface builder as i registered it in the viewdidload method.

Comment: but how does the instance of UITableViewCell class have a reference to  your custom label ? The register class method just lets `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` return a non nil cell. You still need to get the instance of your ItemCellTableViewCell to make your custom label appear.

Comment: hey Navin, I also just spotted that. Thanks. I changed my tableview to self.tableview so it gets the correct custom cell with all the image views and labels inside the custom cell but the it gets the incorrect(small) height for the custom cell and so the search results are overlapping.

Thanks again for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get a reference of your tableView and then in 
`- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomTableCell";
    MyCell *cell = (MyCell *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    ...
}`